# Multiple Checkbox with Toggle Value

Tags: angular, typescript

My requirement is to have a three check box with some certain condition which clicking on the checkbox.

For example, consider three check box 1, 2, and 3

If I select on the 1 checkbox other two checkbox should need to be enable (2, 3).

If I change to `false` (1) then other two checkbox need to be disable (2, 3).

And another condition, if I unchecked the checkbox (1) then other two checkbox value should need to reset false (2, 3) and need to disable.

I have done with above condition. However, what is the problem is the value is not get updated in `ngmodel`.

Below sample code

```
 <td>
              <div class="col-lg-12" id="radiobutton">
                  <input #EDIsRead=ngModel [(ngModel)]="GetRoleIsRead.EDIsRead" name="GetRoleIsRead.EDIsRead" class="form-check-input col-sm-2"
                  type="checkbox" id="EDIsRead" style="padding-left: 0px !important;" (change)="CheckeventforRead('ED')">
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="col-lg-12" id="radiobutton">
                  <input #EDIsModifyLOB=ngModel [(ngModel)]="GetRoleIsModifyLOB.EDIsModifyLOB" name="GetRoleIsModifyLOB.EDIsModifyLOB" class="form-check-input col-sm-2"
                  type="checkbox" id="EDIsModifyLOB" style="padding-left: 0px !important;" (change)="CheckeventforModifyLOB('ED','0')">
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="col-lg-12" id="radiobutton">
                  <input #EDIsModifyAll=ngModel [(ngModel)]="GetRoleIsModifyAll.EDIsModifyAll" name="GetRoleIsModifyAll.EDIsModifyAll" class="form-check-input col-sm-2"
                  type="checkbox" id="EDIsModifyAll" style="padding-left: 0px !important;" (change)="CheckeventforModifyAll('ED','0')">
              </div>
            </td>`
```

Input passing `true true false`.

So, here I am passing `true` for 1, `true` for 2, and `false` for 3 which is two way binding.

If I change the 3 to `true` then 2 got unchecked but value is not changing

Here is my sample json.

Before:

```
{"GetRoleIsRead.EDIsRead": true, "GetRoleIsModifyLOB.EDIsModifyLOB": false, "GetRoleIsModifyAll.EDIsModifyAll": true }
```

After check the 2ed:

```
{"GetRoleIsRead.EDIsRead": true, "GetRoleIsModifyLOB.EDIsModifyLOB": true, "GetRoleIsModifyAll.EDIsModifyAll": true }
```

Actual output should need to be:

```
{"GetRoleIsRead.EDIsRead": true, "GetRoleIsModifyLOB.EDIsModifyLOB": true, "GetRoleIsModifyAll.EDIsModifyAll": false}
```

Comment: this is trivial if you were to use reactive forms, you would add `(change)` events to trigger changes. do you want example or are you definately using template forms no matter what?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your meaning,
I made an example with [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h4xusd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) if this is what you need just say that, and I will explain it more.

A short explanation - I used `[disabled]` property in order to enable/disable inputs, then I used `(change)` event to clear the values of the variables.

Comment: Thanks Michal. I have done with the same logic using jquery by picking the value fro m hidden textbox.

Comment: @AravindhanR Happy to hear that it helped you!